# Rails not rendering public/index.html file; blank page in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, heroku, react-router

I have a problem with my *Rails + React* app when I deploy it to *Heroku*. The React client is inside a `client/` directory of the Rails app. Due to using `react-router`, the Rails server needs to know to render the `index.html` from the React build. When I deploy the client on Heroku, a script copies the content from `client/build/.` to the Rails app's `public/` dir.

Now here is the problem: when my route detects a path like example.com/about it tries to render `public/index.html`. Here is the method:

```
def fallback_index_html
   render file: "public/index.html"
end
```

However, the contents from this file *are not sent to the browser*. I get a blank page. I have added a `puts "hit fallback_index_html"` in the method and confirmed that this method is being hit. I have also opened the file in puts each line to confirm the file has the required html (this is what appeared in the logs from that puts and what SHOULD be sent to the browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Simple Bubble</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.65027555.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.21a8553c.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The most recent fix I tried was going into `config/environments/production.rb` and changing `config.public_file_server.enabled` to `true`. This did not help.

Comment: I think on heroku your front end can't be hidden in a directory. It needs to be in the root of the folder you deploy. I would suggest creating two heroku deployments one for your backend and one for your front end. Then ping the backend link you get once deployed on heroku.

Comment: @GavinThomas Keep in mind that hitting the root of the web app actually works. It is only when going to anything other than root that serves a blank page. The reason going to root works is because the React build is in public/index.html so it is served before the Rails app goes to routes.rb. Otherwise, if we do not hit the root, the Rails app falls back on the `fallback_index_html` method, which is happening, but the render of the index.html file is not working.

Comment: What do you see if you go to `https://yourdomain/static/js/main.21a8553c.js`?

Comment: @norbertpy a big chunk of js!

Comment: Could be a working directory issue, have you tried: render file: Rails.root.join(“public/index.html”)

Comment: @sj26 I just tried and unfortunately it gets the same behaviour. No error but just serves a blank page with a 200 response, like before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using Rails API, so my `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`.

From Rails API docs it says:

> The default API Controller stack includes all renderers, which means you can use render :json and brothers freely in your controllers. Keep in mind that templates are not going to be rendered, so you need to ensure your controller is calling either render or redirect_to in all actions, otherwise it will return 204 No Content.

Thus Rails API only cannot render HTML! The following allowed me to render the html without including everything from `ActionController::Base`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds

  def fallback_index_html
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render body: Rails.root.join('public/index.html').read }
    end
  end
end
```

The reason I am including `ActionController::MimeResponds` is to have access to the `respond_to` method.

My Rails application now renders index.html from my public directory when a subdirectory is hit and my React client / react-router takes over from there.

Comment: Does `fallback_index_html` method from Rails or it is defined by you?

Comment: Why `format.html { render body: Rails.root.join('public/index.html').read }` but not `format.html { render file: "public/index.html" }` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I would have to test but this setup is for a wonky react app inside the rails structure. It isn’t just serving a file; it needs to hit it so the react will render. Here is the repo: https://github.com/stevenpslade/bubble-tutorial-api

Comment: @ArupRakshit Check out routes and the client dir to see what’s going on

Comment: Just tested, not sure why `format.html { render file: "public/index.html" }` doesn't work.. Very strange to me.. But thanks to you for your prompt reply bro. :)

Comment: This was super helpful for rendering a create-react-app served from the public directory of an API only app. Thank you! @ArupRakshit I assume the reading/serving is to skirt around the fact that the rails app is API only and is missing some functions to natively render html.